# Add multiple user or role on AWS Lambda policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, command-line-interface

I'm trying to invoke an `AWS Lambda` from one account on another account, I have the private link created for both and tried configuring a role and adding it to the was lambda polices it works as expected, but I want to limit to the individual user to invoke the function. So is it possible to add multiple users instead of root or role `ARN`?

The `CLI` command will add the root as below:

```
$ aws lambda add-permission --function-name my-function:prod --statement-id xaccount --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
--principal 210987654321 --output text
{"Sid":"xaccount","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::210987654321:root"},"Action":"lambda:InvokeFunction","Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function"}
```

Comment: you should put an API Gateway in front of this lambda...not invoke directly like this. Otherwise, you need to allow an "Assume Role" IAM: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Answer (score 0):

From [Using resource-based policies for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html):

> To limit access to a user, group, or role in another account, specify the full ARN of the identity as the principal. For example: `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/developer`

Comment: Is there a way I can add multiple user accounts? If I try running the CLI command with a different user ARN getting an error statement ID already exist.

Comment: The error is probably related to `"Sid":"xaccount"` -- try using a different value for the Sid (or even leave it out).